# npm "is known not to run on" installed node.js version, but I'm using a version it lists being compatible with in the error

Tags: node.js, npm

I am attempting to install a newer version of node and npm. The installed version of node is 18.3.0, as veritifed by

```
<test> node --version
v18.3.0
```

However, when I attempt to use `npm`, it complains that it won't run on v18.3.0, even though it also claims that it supports "`>=18.0.0`".

```
<test> npm --version
ERROR: npm v9.7.1 is known not to run on Node.js v18.3.0.  This version of npm supports the following node versions: `^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0`. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/.

ERROR:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\npmv\9.7.1\node_modules\@npmcli\config:1
../../workspaces/config
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1069:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:827:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\npmv\9.7.1\lib\npm.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
```

Update: I installed nodejs 18.16.0 and I get the same errors

```
ERROR: npm v9.7.1 is known not to run on Node.js v18.16.0.  This version of npm supports the following node versions: `^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0`. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/.

ERROR:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\npmv\9.7.1\node_modules\@npmcli\config:1
../../workspaces/config
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1176:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\npmv\9.7.1\lib\npm.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to update Node.js to a version that is compatible with npm 9.7.1.

To solve this install the latest LTS (Long-Term Support) version.

```
npm install -g npm@16.13.0
```

Comment: But isn't node 18.3.0 compatible with npm 9.7.1? It says so right there in the error message!

Your command gives the same compatiblity and syntax errors as I posted above for `npm --version`

Comment: Also, I just updated to node 18.16.0, the very latest version according to nodejs.org and it gives me the same errors.

Comment: in this case, It's possible that there is a problem with the npm installation. Clear the npm cache `npm cache clean --force`, and reinstall npm `npm install -g npm@latest`. Then verify the installation `npm --version`

 if you're using a package manager like Nodist to manage multiple Node.js versions, make sure that the version you're currently using (18.3.0 or 18.16.0) is properly selected and configured within Nodist.